# Communicating with android device from Windows PC via USB

Tags: android, windows, usb, drivers

I have android device and windows drivers for it.
I have to communicate using my own binary protocol in accessory mode.
Is it possible to send data to this device without writing custom USB driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB is a complex protocol because it is *'universal'* and can handle a large variety of devices (mass storage, cameras,...). So on your android device has to be implemented a basic USB structure to use standard libraries like *libusb* or something like that.
You can assume that this is the case, because android is in most cases used on processors with USB port.

See http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml.

You can get more information about the USB device classes, interfaces, configurations, endpoints ur android device impmenets by using `libusb -v`

Then if you know what the USB structure on your android device looks like you can use *libusb* or another library to write data to specific endpoints in the usb structure by e.g. `libusb_bulk_transfer()`, `libusb_control_transfer()`

http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/io.html

If you want to program in java you can use usb4java however this is a bit flaky http://usb4java.org/quickstart/libusb.html

The general USB structure is **device -> (configuration) -> interface -> endpoint**

So the way to write data to an endpoint is:

```
libusb_init(NULL); 
libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, vendor_id, product_id);
libusb_claim_interface(devh, 0);
libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle, (2 | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT), data, 
        4, &p, 0); //example
... release interface...
...
libusb_close(devh);
libusb_exit(NULL);
```

Here is C++ example copied from http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libusb.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    libusb_device **devs; //pointer to pointer of device, used to      
                            retrieve a list of devices
    libusb_device_handle *dev_handle; //a device handle
    libusb_context *ctx = NULL; //a libusb session

    int r; //for return values
    ssize_t cnt; //holding number of devices in list
    r = libusb_init(&ctx); //initialize the library for the session we 
                             just declared
    if(r < 0) {
        cout<<"Init Error "<<r<<endl; //there was an error
        return 1;
    }
    libusb_set_debug(ctx, 3); //set verbosity level to 3, as suggested in 
                                the documentation

    cnt = libusb_get_device_list(ctx, &devs); //get the list of devices
    if(cnt < 0) {
        cout<<"Get Device Error"<<endl; //there was an error
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<cnt<<" Devices in list."<<endl;

    dev_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(ctx, 5118, 7424);  
              //these are vendorID and productID I found for my usb device

    if(dev_handle == NULL)
        cout<<"Cannot open device"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Device Opened"<<endl;
    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1); //free the list, unref the devices 
                                         in it

    unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[4]; //data to write

    data[0]='a';data[1]='b';data[2]='c';data[3]='d'; //some dummy values

    int actual; //used to find out how many bytes were written
    if(libusb_kernel_driver_active(dev_handle, 0) == 1) { //find out if 
                                               kernel driver is attached
        cout<<"Kernel Driver Active"<<endl;
        if(libusb_detach_kernel_driver(dev_handle, 0) == 0) //detach it
            cout<<"Kernel Driver Detached!"<<endl;
    }
    r = libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle, 0); //claim interface 0 (the   
    first) of device (mine had jsut 1)
    if(r < 0) {
        cout<<"Cannot Claim Interface"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<"Claimed Interface"<<endl;

    cout<<"Data->"<<data<<"<-"<<endl; //just to see the data we want to 
    write : abcd
    cout<<"Writing Data..."<<endl;
    r = libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle, (2 | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT), data, 
    4, &actual, 0); //my device's out endpoint was 2, found with trial- 
    the device had 2 endpoints: 2 and 129
    if(r == 0 && actual == 4) //we wrote the 4 bytes successfully
        cout<<"Writing Successful!"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Write Error"<<endl;

    r = libusb_release_interface(dev_handle, 0); //release the claimed 
                                                    interface
    if(r!=0) {
        cout<<"Cannot Release Interface"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<"Released Interface"<<endl;    

    libusb_close(dev_handle); //close the device we opened
    libusb_exit(ctx); //needs to be called to end the
    delete[] data; //delete the allocated memory for data
    return 0;
}
```

So as your device runs android it has a USB structure/functionality. To investigate the USB functionality of your device (device class like *mass storage, RNDIS,...*) use `libusb -v` and the see the code above to write custom data to one of the endpoints on the device.